# If I define two loop variables in the for loop, how do I update the loop variables

Tags: java

As follows, I want to reverse the array. But my code doesn't work. This is my for loop. Please take a look. Is this for loop right.Codes are below.

```
int[] array = new int[]{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19};
System.out.println("Before reversal:");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
}

for (int i = 0,j = array.length - i - 1; i < j; i++) {  
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

System.out.println();
System.out.println("After reversal:");
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: Please add a tag for your target language.

Comment: What do you need it for? If it's just for `print` purpose, you can simply reverse your index from `array.length - 1` back to `0`, and change your increment to `i--`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array.length/2; i++) {
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length-i-1];
    array[array.length-i-1] = temp;
}
```

The conditional in the for-loop is integer division, meaning this will work with arrays of both even and odd lengths.

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0,j = array.length - i - 1; i < j; i++) {  
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
```

The value of j is never updated, and the initial value of j should be array.length-1 because i is just 0.
You have 3 options, the first changing the for statement:

```
   for(int i=0, j=array.length-1; i<j; i++, j--) //YOUR CODE
```

The second would be changing the last assignment to `array[j--] = temp;`

And the third would be adding a `j--;` after the last assignemnt.

Any of them should solve your problem.

Comment: So if I define two loop variables in a for loop, I have to declare the update of the two loop variables in parentheses, right. I just don't understand why `j` never chaged in my code.

Comment: Thanks bro. I know why the value of j is never updated. That's because the initialization of the loop variable value in the for loop is performed only once. And after that, the value of i can update but j cant't update. Thanks a lot.